# Extract data from queryset

Tags: python, django

Models.py

```
class MasterItems(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ShipperItems_owner')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", null=True)

    length = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    breadth = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    weight = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)


class SalesOrderItems(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(MasterItems, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class SalesOrder(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='so_owner')
    client = models.ForeignKey(MasterClient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='so_client')
    items = models.ManyToManyField(SalesOrderItems, related_name='items_so', blank=True, null=True)
```

From the frontend I am receiving `pk` of sales order for e.g `[4,2]` and I want to extract the Items associated with these `SalesOrder`

What I tried:

```
        items = []

        for i in sales_orders:

            so_items = SalesOrderItems.objects.filter(items_so=i)
            print("so_items ", so_items)

            items.append(so_items)
```

But the output I get is this:

```
items = [<QuerySet [<SalesOrderItems: SalesOrderItems object (4)>, <SalesOrderItems: SalesOrderItems object (5)>]>, <QuerySet [<SalesOrderItems: SalesOrderItems object (1)>]>]
```

How can I get the items weight ?
Actually SalesOrderItems has item_quantity and I want to multiply that quantity with the item weight to get the total weight of items

Comment: SalesOrderItems.objects.filter(items_so=i).values('item__name')

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan Actually `SalesOrderItems` has `item_quantity` and I want to multiply that quantity with the item weight

Comment: Then please edit the question so it's clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan I am sorry, see the updated question

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Do a single query(optional, it's just an optimization):

```
queryset = SalesOrderItems.objects.filter(items_so__pk__in=sales_orders)
```

Then multiply like below:

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, F, ExpressionWrapper

items = queryset.annotate(total_weight=ExpressionWrapper(
    F('item_quantity') * F('item__weight'), output_field=FloatField())
```

Each object in queryset will have a new attribute called `total_weight` and that's the value that you need.

```
for item in items:
    item.total_weight # this is what you are looking for
```

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax, idk why

Comment: I tried this but got `<QuerySet [<SalesOrderItems: SalesOrderItems object (1)>, <SalesOrderItems: SalesOrderItems object (4)>, <SalesOrderItems: SalesOrderItems object (5)>]>`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Unless your data volumes are really small, batch calculations like this should be done in SQL on the database (i.e. using the Django db expressions as shown) - you should not bring all items back to the app to do the calc on each item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values` method and include inside columns you want to use

```
items =[]
for i in sales_orders:
  so_items = SalesOrderItems.objects.filter (items_so = i).values(
        'item__name',
        'item_quantity'
    )
  print ("so_items ", so_items) items.append (so_items)
```